# Looking for help to ping multiple hostnames on a text file and output certain data to another text file

Tags: ping

I have over 3000 servers I need to ping in my corporate network.  I found a way to ping them but I am hoping to find away to output the ping data to another text file or xls file with the hostname, ip address and the response/reply back information without having to look through 300000 lines of data and remove repeating data given from a typical dos ping.

Comment: Why do you need to ping 3000 servers? Certainly there are better/more reliable ways to monitor uptime and availability? And ICMP echo doesn't necessarily mean that things are working, after all.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? No good can come of what you're describing...

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a tool called `nmap`.

Example:
`nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24` would ping all hosts between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.254 and provide a list of the hosts that respond as output.

That being said, if you are trying to inventory or monitor your network, there are more professional ways to go about it. For example, tools like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) can check whether certain services are operating normally and generate alerts if they are down. [Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) are additional options that may or may not be more appropriate for your (mysterious) situation.

Comment: And `-oG` and `-oX` will output in greppable and XML formats respectively.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [fping](http://fping.sourceforge.net/) or [Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) if you're looking to manage a list of availability across those 3000 hosts. `fping` works in parallel, and it will take the input file containing a  list of systems. Observium would be a nice lightweight monitoring system.

But in general, you should provide more insight into what you're trying to accomplish.